# sql stored procedure - Having problems retreiving multiple rows of data with Idatareader

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures, idatareader

I have a stored procedure that does this:

```
SELECT TOP 4 FROM dbo.test
```

(table contains 5 rows)

My c# code is:

```
IDataReader test= ((IDataReader)(DataProvider.Instance().ExecuteReader("fetchtest")));
 test.Read();
 title1.Text = test.GetString(0);
 title2.Text = test.GetString(1);
 title3.Text = test.GetString(2);
 title4.Text = test.GetString(3);
```

However I can only display 0 and 1. 2+ will give me an index error. Is there a better way to retrieve all rows?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like a1ex07 said, GetString gets the nth column. Here is a complete code sample.

```
List<string> titles = new List<string>();
using (IDataReader test = ((IDataReader)(DataProvider.Instance().ExecuteReader("fetchtest"))))
{
    while (test.Read())
    {
       titles.Add(test.GetString(0));
    }
}


title1.Text = titles[0];
title2.Text = titles[1];
title3.Text = titles[2];
title4.Text = titles[3];
```

Answer (score 2):

`IDataReader.GetString(2)` returns the value of the third column, not record. You need to use [Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.read.aspx) method to advance to the next record.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. So how would I get all the data from the select TOP 4? Is there another way to dump the information?

Comment: Take a look on the link I added. It has a sample code you can reuse.